# ActiveX object custom event does not show results

Tags: javascript, c#, html, com, event-handling

**tl/dr**

The managed C# COM visible object that I created has an event. In the "OnCardRead" method (which fires the actual event) I check to see if the event is subscribed to and it is. The event callback code in javascript appears to never be called.

**The story**

The project is simple. Create a webpage that "opens" a rfid device and returns the serial number of the card. That portion of has its own set of unit tests and works just fine. To help my self debug if the Serial Ports address is set to 0 then it uses my MockRfidSDK. But for the sake of being thorough here is the code surrounding that (minus the actual RFID code).

**IRfidDevice**

```
[Guid("E86A9038-368D-4e8f-B389-FDEF38935B2F"), InterfaceType(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsDual), ComVisible(true)]
public interface IRfidDevice
{
    [DispId(1)]
    int Open();

    [DispId(2)]
    int Close();

    [DispId(3)]
    void SetComPort(int comport);

    [DispId(4)]
    void FlashLed(int led);
}
```

**IRfidEvent**

```
[ComVisible(true), GuidAttribute("0422D916-C11A-474e-947D-45A107038D12"), InterfaceTypeAttribute(ComInterfaceType.InterfaceIsIDispatch)]
public interface IRfidEvent
{
    [DispIdAttribute(0x60020000)]
    void CardUidReceived(byte sak, ushort atq, string uid);
}
```

**RfidSdk/EmptyRfidSdk**

```
internal interface RfidSdk
{
    void Open();
    int GetCard();
    byte[] SelectCard();
    int Close();
    void FlashLed(int led);
}

class EmptyRfidSdk : RfidSdk
{
    public void Open()
    {
    }

    public int GetCard()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(10);
        return 0x0344;
    }

    public byte[] SelectCard()
    {
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
        return new byte[] { 0x20, 0x44, 0x03, 0x31, 0x32, 0x33, 0x34, 0x35, 0x36, 0x37 };
    }

    public int Close()
    {
        return 0;
    }

    public void FlashLed(int led)
    {
    }
}
```

**RfidDevice**

```
[Guid("873355E1-2D0D-476f-9BEF-C7E645024C32"), ProgId("MasterRDActiveX.RfidDevice"), ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.None), ComDefaultInterface(typeof(IRfidDevice)), ComVisible(true), ComSourceInterfaces(typeof(IRfidEvent))]
public class RfidDevice : InternetSafeObject, IRfidDevice
{
    private RfidSdk sdk;
    private bool _searchForCard = false;

    [ComVisible(false)]
    public delegate void RfidEventHandler(byte sak, ushort atq, string uid);

    public event RfidEventHandler CardUidReceived;

    public int Open()
    {
        try
        {
            sdk.Open();
            _searchForCard = true;
            Task.Factory.StartNew(SearchForCard);
            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.TraceError(ex.Message);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public int Close()
    {
        try
        {
            _searchForCard = false;
            sdk.Close();
            sdk = null;
            return 0;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Trace.TraceError(ex.Message);
            return -1;
        }
    }

    public void SetComPort(int comport)
    {
        if (sdk != null) Close();
        if (comport < 1)
        {
            sdk = new EmptyRfidSdk();
        }
        else
        {
            sdk = new MasterRDWrapper.MasterRD(comport);
        }
    }

    public void FlashLed(int led)
    {
        sdk.FlashLed(led);
    }

    private void SearchForCard()
    {
        while (_searchForCard)
        {
            int temp = 0;
            while ((temp = sdk.GetCard()) == 0)
            {
            }
            if (temp == sdk.GetCard())
            {
                var card = sdk.SelectCard();
                FireCardUidReceived(card[0], BitConverter.ToUInt16(card, 1), card.Skip(3).ToArray());
            }
        }
    }

    private void FireCardUidReceived(byte sak, ushort atq, byte[] uid)
    {
        if (CardUidReceived != null)
        {
            Console.Beep(1000,100);
            CardUidReceived(sak, atq, BitConverter.ToString(uid));
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Beep(2000, 2000);
        }
    }
```

So that code is working just fine. Remember the beeps. Short beep means the Event is subscribed to, long beep means it's not being subscribed too.

Now the webpage is where things get a little murky for me. I've looked at a lot of ActiveX tutorials here are some rules about the HTML code. It can't use deprecated HTML tags (IE... OBJECT). Here is my solution thus far

**rfidScript.js**

```
function onRfidCard(a, b, c) {
    console.log('I am in your event');
    document.getElementById('result').innerHTML = c;
    console.log('all done in your event');
}
function tryRfid(rfidDevice) {
    var uidTag = document.getElementById('result');
    var comPort =  parseInt(document.getElementById('comPortBox').value);

    if (rfidDevice != null) {
        rfidDevice.SetComPort(comPort);
        if (rfidDevice.Open() === 0) {
            uidTag.innerHTML = "Please Tap Card";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('error').innerHTML = "Failed to Open";
        }
    }
}
function closeRfid(rfidDevice) {
    rfidDevice.Close();
}
```

and last bit the html code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>RFID ActiveX Test</title>
    <!--//C:\Users\snyder\Source\Repos\xPD\MasterRDActiveX\MasterRDActiveX\bin\Debug\testRfid.html-->
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ctrl = new ActiveXObject('MasterRDActiveX.RfidDevice');
        eval('function ctrl::CardUidReceived(a,b,c){ onRfidCard(a,b,c); }');
    </script>
    <script src="rfidScript.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>This is our Active X Test Page for RFID</h1>
    <input type="text" id="comPortBox" /> <br />
    <button type="button" onclick="tryRfid(ctrl);">Open</button>
    <button type="button" onclick="closeRfid(ctrl);">Close</button>
    <h2>
        <output id="error" style="color: red;"></output>
        <output id="result"></output>
    </h2>

</body>
</html>
```

I fire up IE, put 0 in the textbox, click open and I hear 1 short beep(and only one.. not sure why on that one as I would expect a beep every 2 seconds *see note1*), but I don't see any text show up in the result output tag (and I've tried using alert to no avail.) So why?????? what am I missing?

***Note 1*** - Earlier when I was getting long beeps it would long beep over and over again as I would expect.

Comment: What happens if you put the `script` tag iwth `rfid.js` before the other script tag? Also, from my experience, the number of the parameters has to match; perhaps the names also have to match.

Comment: ha.. wow that was a long time ago and I don't work at that company anymore, so i can't test this out. Thank you though for trying.